# MySQL limit results per category

Tags: sql, mysql

Each item in c_data is in a category/section. I would like to limit how many items are displayed per category, rather than limiting the total number of items retrieved. Obviously if I add something like "limit 20" to the query, it will only fetch 20 results in total, rather than 20 results per category.

```
   SELECT cm.id,
                cm.title AS cmtitle,
                cm.sectionid,
                cm.type AS cmtype,
                cd.id,
                cd.time,
                cd.link,
                cd.title,
                cd.description,
                cd.sectionid AS sectionid
      FROM c_main AS cm
      JOIN c_data AS cd ON cd.sectionid=cm.sectionid
     WHERE cd.sectionid=cm.sectionid 
     ORDER by id ASC
```

The field with the category is "sectionid".

Comment: It is being included. The c_main table contains 5 categories, and the c_data table contains the information that corresponds to those categories. Most of the categories' data (in c_data) have 5-10 items, and one has over 80 items currently.

Comment: @nsan: Make sure to accept the answer that solved your problem (I guess it's OMG Ponies' in that case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have any ranking functionality, but you can use a variable to create a psuedo row number.

Use:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM (SELECT cm.id,
               cm.title AS cmtitle,
               cm.sectionid,
               cm.type AS cmtype,
               cd.id AS cd_id,
               cd.time,
               cd.link,
               cd.title,
               cd.description,
               cd.sectionid AS cd_sectionid,
               CASE
                 WHEN @sectionid != cm.sectionid THEN @rownum := 1 
                 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1
               END AS rank,
               @sectionid := cm.sectionid
          FROM C_MAIN cm,
               C_DATA cd,
               (SELECT @rownum := 0, @sectionid := NULL) r
         WHERE cm.sectionid = cd.sectionid
      ORDER BY cm.sectionid) x
 WHERE x.rank <= 20
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: I think you are missing a `,` after `END AS rank`. Would your solution work if sectionid's are not sorted?

Comment: A syntax error is given with this, even after adding a comma after     END AS rank.

Comment: It was missing two commas - `cd.sectionid AS sectionid,`, and after `AS rank`

Comment: @Peter: True about sorting by sectionid to ensure that the numbering is correct.  Because it will only increment when they are different, there's a change that a lot of them would have a rank of 1/etc.

Comment: @nsan: I added column aliases, because you have `cm.id` and `cd.id`.  Otherwise, it's not obvious where you could get a duplicate id error unless you aren't using the table aliases as provided in my answer.

Comment: Working now. The issue now is that it doesn't limit the results correctly. Some of the categories will show over 40 results unless I lower the limit, which also further lowers the others.

Comment: I tried this solution, and it just works fine. It returns 20 rows for `test3` (as this sectionid has more than 20 rows), and all rows for the other sectionids in your provided test-data.

Comment: I should have looked at the obvious, which is the php code being used to display said results. The mysql statement works fine otherwise.

Comment: This is a slow query , it will take ages of 1M records !

Comment: Here is a faster version i found and use on the internet : http://forum.okitoo.net/trick-select-x-rows-records-for-each-category-in-a-table-t322.html

Answer (score 4):

The answers to this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990977/mysql-avg-function-for-recent-15-records-by-date-order-date-desc-in-every-symbo) should help you to solve that problem.

**EDIT**:

It should work with using [row numbers](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/27/simulating-the-sql-row_number-function/).

I have not tried it, but this should work:

```
set @section = '';
set @num  = 1;

SELECT y.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
      x.*, 
      @num := if(@section = sectionid, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @section := sectionid
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
          cm.id AS cm_id,
          cm.title AS cmtitle,
          cm.sectionid,
          cm.type AS cmtype,
          cd.id AS cd_id,
          cd.time,
          cd.link,
          cd.title,
          cd.description
        FROM c_main AS cm
        JOIN c_data AS cd ON ( cd.sectionid=cm.sectionid )
        ORDER by cd.sectionid ASC, cm.id ASC
    ) x
) y
WHERE y.row_number <= 20;
```

Comment: The initial intention of the question was to take the last 15 rows, not days. astander's answer points to using rownumbers. I'm going to provide a better answer though, unless you beat me ;-)

Comment: +1: It was your algorithm after all, I was just quicker at implementing it.

Comment: This throws up a syntax error right away, so I'm not able to test it.

Comment: @nsan: I added some aliases, so could you please try the code again? If it still does not work, could you please post the error you get?

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set @num = 1; SELECT y.* FROM ( SELECT x.*, @num := if' at line 2"

Comment: As you seem to have a problem with pre-initializing the variables, I'd suggest to use the solution provided by OMG Ponies. I tried both of our versions, and they return the same (in my opinion correct) result.