# Wordpress custom query to get last edited post with specific category

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to get a list of posts marked as portfolios that are marked as a specific category.  For that category, I then need to limit each result set per category and also only get the latest updated post for each post.

My current query is this:

```
SELECT $wpdb->posts.*, $wpdb->terms.slug
                    FROM $wpdb->posts
                    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
                    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
                    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
                    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
                    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
                    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'portfolio'
                    AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW()
                    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
                    AND $wpdb->terms.slug IN ('".implode("','", $category_array)."')
                    ORDER BY
                        Case When $wpdb->terms.slug = 'residential' Then 1 
                            When $wpdb->terms.Slug = 'recreational' Then 1 
                            When $wpdb->terms.Slug = 'civic' Then 1 
                            When $wpdb->terms.Slug = 'contact' Then 2 
                            When $wpdb->terms.Slug = 'blog' Then 3 
                            When $wpdb->terms.Slug = 'services' Then 4 
                            When $wpdb->terms.Slug = 'team' Then 5
                            Else 6
                        End
```

I'm going to use something like this ([MySQL limit results per category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000744/mysql-limit-results-per-category)) to get a set limit for each category.

However, this returns every version of the same post currently.  I'm not really sure how to go about getting only the latest version of the post.  I know how I "could" go about doing that, but highly doubt it's the best way.  Does anyone know of a standardized way of getting the latest post with a custom query like this?

Also, I'm not necessarily committed to the custom query. I just don't know how I'd create this query using arguments with the `WP_Query()` function.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using a sub query.  Here is what I used.

```
$querystr = "SELECT x.*
                        FROM (
                            SELECT y.*,
                                CASE
                                    WHEN @category != y.slug THEN @rownum := 1 
                                    ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1
                                END AS rank,
                                @category := y.slug
                                FROM (
                                    SELECT $wpdb->posts.*,
                                        $wpdb->terms.slug
                                    FROM $wpdb->posts
                                        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
                                        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
                                        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
                                        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
                                    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
                                        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'portfolio'
                                        AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW()
                                        AND $wpdb->terms.slug IN ('".implode("','", $category_array)."')
                                        AND $wpdb->posts.ID NOT IN
                                            (
                                                SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID
                                                    FROM $wpdb->posts
                                                    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
                                                    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
                                                    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
                                                    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
                                                    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
                                                    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'portfolio'
                                                    AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW()
                                                    AND $wpdb->terms.slug IN ('".implode("','", $category_array)."')
                                                    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'revision'
                                                    GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID
                                            )
                                    GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID
                                    ORDER BY $wpdb->terms.slug
                                ) y
                                LEFT JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @category := NULL) r ON (1 = 1)
                        ) x
                        WHERE x.rank <= 10
                        ORDER BY
                            Case When x.slug = 'residential' Then 1 
                                When x.Slug = 'recreational' Then 1 
                                When x.Slug = 'civic' Then 1 
                                When x.Slug = 'contact' Then 2 
                                When x.Slug = 'blog' Then 3 
                                When x.Slug = 'services' Then 4 
                                When x.Slug = 'team' Then 5
                                Else 6
                            End,
                            rand()";
```